# Warning: reference to undefined property this[a]

Tags: google-maps, firebug

I'm getting this warning in Firebug.

> Warning: reference to undefined property this[a] Source File:
>   http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/7/0/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js
>   Line: 26

I'm working on a Google Map plugin for my WordPress site. Do I need to worry about it? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, I think this is a legitimate question. My code works fine. I'm getting this warning above from some minified Google Map js, which isn't readable/understandable. Am I going to have a problem down the line or can I safely ignore it. Has anyone come across this warning before? Thank you.

Comment: Did I say at any point that it was not?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, Apparently, because you closed my question. In any event, refhat answered it. I understand that the moderators want to keep the board clean, but I think that they should be a bit more forgiving. In any event, the problem's solved.

Comment: I asked that before you could see that I voted to close it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most common error I have seen in, while playing with google-maps api. I would not say leave it like that, though your code works but you can take it as  a kind of warning that probably depends on your location, where you are loading your maps:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/9fce9c1a493b3413

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's interesting that other people are encountering the probolem. I ended up moving where I load the google maps from one script to another. I don't get an error now, I just get a warning.